# reverse debugging with lldb

Tags: lldb, reverse-debugging

I've read [this tutorial](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html), but I haven't found there anything about reverse debugging. Does lldb have some features like `target record` in gdb? If yes, where can I read about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not yet.  To date most of the work on lldb has been to complete the common set of debugger features; it is solid for i386, x86_64, and armv7 debugging on Mac systems.  There are people woking on Linux and *BSD ports now - that's hugely important to making lldb usable for lots of people.  There are lots of interesting features that can be added to lldb in the future as the core debugger facilities are mature -- genuine reverse execution is one, process recording & playback (what I gather `target record` does) is another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah, I meant process recording.

Answer (score 4):

There is this work from last year: https://dev.to/vangelists/live-reverse-debugging-in-lldb-2nf0
https://github.com/vangelists/llvm-project

But looks like it's just a prototype and hasn't been upstreamed so far.

Comment: this looks promising, thanks for the link. i'm curious how does it compare to `rr` tool.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting https://lldb.llvm.org/resources/projects.html#reverse-debugging :

> This is kind of a holy grail, it’s hard to support for complex apps (many threads, shared memory, etc.) But it would be SO nice to have…